# Binding Data in Angular 2 (ES5)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular, ecmascript-5

I am having trouble using data model binding in Angular 2.0 written in ES5 Javascript. I created a ToDo list following the Angular tutorial and various other sources, but I was not successful when trying to add ToDo items from an asynchronous request (either from a db or just added an item after a request is made).

The data will update, but it won't show up in the DOM until I call an `$event` or somehow force Angular or Zone.js to go through another cycle.

Also, the only browser that this plunker works in is Chrome, so I'm not sure what is wrong there either.

Any help on any of those things would be appreciated!

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/p3Ipvw4SNut0XLOn76kJ?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker works great in firefox, I can add as many items I want.

Comment: @TanaseButcaru it may just be my version of FireFox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Angular2 alpha. It's resolved and committed, but has not made its way to a release yet.
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/issues/24